# Utilisation du conditionnel — par les exemples

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical, subjonctif, conditionnel

Il y a peut-être une douzaine des structures grammaticales dont je ne suis jamais sûre de la traduction en Français.

Et maintenant j’aimerais finalement commencer à réduire ce nombre.

Donc, voici ma question:

Est-ce que les deux phrases suivantes sont correctes ou seulement une ou peut-être aucune?

Exemple 1:

> English: I would have never thought that you would stay.
>
> Français: Je n’aurais jamais imaginé que tu restes.

(conditionnel passé + subjonctif présent)

———————

Exemple 2:

> English: She would have never thought that he’d stay.
>
> Français: Elle n’aurait jamais imaginé qu’il restât.

(conditionnel passé + subjonctif passé)

Peut-être peut-on aussi dire la phrase comme ça?

> Je n’aurais jamais imaginé que tu va rester.
>
> Je n’aurais jamais imaginé que tu allais rester.
>
> Je n’aurais jamais imaginé que tu ailles rester.

Merci de votre aide!

Answer (score 2):

**I** The translation of the first sentence is correct.

**II** The first translation of the second sentence is correct but it is proper only in the literary tongue; it is not used at all in the spoken language nor in  everyday written language (letters to friends, letters from and to the administrations, …).

- Elle n’aurait jamais imaginé qu’il restât.

There are problems with the first and third of the other possibilities;

- <s>Je n’aurais jamais imaginé que tu va rester.</s>
- Je n’aurais jamais imaginé que tu allais rester. (*That will do but this next option is more factual.*)
  Je n’aurais jamais imaginé que tu serais resté.
- <s>Je n’aurais jamais imaginé que tu ailles rester.</s>

"Je n’aurais jamais imaginé que tu allais rester."   is more appropriately the translation of

- "I would never have thought that you were going to stay.".

Answer (score 2):

Les deux phrases en anglais utilisent le conditionnel (*would stay*) et peuvent être traduites aussi par un conditionnel en français :

Exemple 1 :

> *I would have never thought that **you would stay***.
>
> Je n'aurais jamais pensé que **tu resterais**.

Ici, le deuxième conditionnel est temporel. Il indique un futur par rapport au (conditionnel) passé du verbe penser.

Exemple 2 :

> *She would have never thought that **he'd stay***.
>
> Elle n'aurait jamais pensé qu'**il resterait**.

---

Si tu veux utiliser un conditionnel passé, ce sera, en anglais :

> *I would have never thought that **you would have stayed**.*

et en français :

> Je n'aurais jamais pensé que **tu serais resté(e)**.

---

Ton utilisation du subjonctif dans les deux phrase suivantes est aussi possible :

> Je n'aurais jamais imaginé **que tu restes**.
>
> Elle n'aurait jamais imaginé **qu'il restât**.

La deuxième est bien sûr d'un registre très littéraire et a pour variante :

> Elle **ne se serait** jamais imaginé **qu'il restât**.

cf.

> Car il ne se serait jamais imaginé qu'en Algérie on **pût** chasser autre chose que le lion.

Alphonse Daudet, *Tartarin de Tarascon*

On trouve aussi l'imparfait du subjonctif dans :

> — Eh bien ! Je n'aurais jamais cru
>   Que vous **fussiez** un sot aussi parfait.

Traduction par Henri Parisot de:

> Ah, well! I hardly thought you
>      So absolute a fool.

Lewis Carroll, *Poeta fit, non nascitur*

> Ah ! Je n'aurais jamais cru que la science **fût** si pesante.

Marivaux

Les deux phrases suivantes sont clairement agrammaticales.

> <s>Je n’aurais jamais imaginé que tu va rester.</s>
>
> Je n’aurais jamais imaginé que tu ailles rester.

La proposition suivante est correcte :

> Je n'aurais jamais imaginé que **tu allais rester**.

mais elle traduit :

> *I would have never thought (imagined) that **you were going to stay***.

Answer (score 2):

La phrase 1."Je n’aurais jamais imaginé que tu restes" est correcte.

La phrase 2 "Elle n’aurait jamais imaginé qu’il restât" est correcte théoriquement, mais très improbable : l'imparfait du subjonctif (qu'il restât) est un temps très littéraire, assez daté et très rarement employé aujourd'hui, sauf dans une langue littéraire, ou par dérision. Or, l'emploi du verbe "imaginer" dans ce sens me paraît assez contemporain, donc difficilement compatible avec l'imparfait du subjonctif.

Les phrases 3 (Je n’aurais jamais imaginé que tu vas rester.) et 5 (Je n’aurais jamais imaginé que tu ailles rester) sont incorrectes.

La phrase 4 "Je n’aurais jamais imaginé que tu allais rester" est tout à fait correcte et c'est peut-être celle qui me semble la plus naturelle (le français est ma langue maternelle).

(Dans le cadre de la concordance des temps, le verbe "aller" employé comme auxiliaire subit les mêmes transformations que les autres ; en revanche, dans une proposition au subjonctif, il est perçu dans son sens fort et ne peut donc être utilisé comme auxiliaire d'un futur composé).